# Return the greatest value of a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this output from a query:

```
IIS7        afsgateway  sharepoint  drupal      j2eeapp     Others      frontpage
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
5637        3691        2321        518         212         107         30
```

I would like to obtain the greatest value and its column name, I mean, `IIS7` and `5637`, but I don't know how to achieve it. Any help, please?

Comment: What's the query that produces this output?

Comment: you can use pivot function

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, the query is simple, I don' see the point of sharing it, but it's `SELECT iis7 + ISNULL(iis7dfs,0) + ISNULL(iis7dfs2,0) AS 'IIS7', afsgateway, sharepoint, ISNULL(drupal,0) as 'drupal', j2eeapp, ntgateway + ISNULL(sp2013,0) + ISNULL(spcommunity,0) AS 'Others', frontpage 
        FROM dbo.WebDirectoryTypeStatistics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT MAX(col1),MAX(col2)
FROM (
  SELECT iis7 + ISNULL(iis7dfs,0) + ISNULL(iis7dfs2,0) AS col1,'IIS7' AS col2
  FROM dbo.WebDirectoryTypeStatistics
UNION AL
  SELECT afsgateway, sharepoint, ISNULL(drupal,0) as col1, 'drupal' AS col2
  FROM dbo.WebDirectoryTypeStatistics
UNION ALL
  SELECT j2eeapp, ntgateway + ISNULL(sp2013,0) + ISNULL(spcommunity,0) AS col1, 
             'Others' AS col2
  FROM dbo.WebDirectoryTypeStatistics
UNION ALL
  SELECT frontpage AS col1, 'frontpage' AS col2  
  FROM dbo.WebDirectoryTypeStatistics
) AS temp
```

I just re-arranged your query so that it returns the values as two columns. `col1` and `col2`. `col1` contains all the maximum values and `col2` contains the corresponding column names.

Comment: Thanks @Nithesh, that did the trick! I edited your code because you didn't notice a couple of things of my query, but your idea was clear enough :)